# Edit variable using variable that contains reference to said variable

Tags: python, pointers, variables

Imagine I have:

```
x = 2
y = x
y = 3
```

Output:

```
x = 2
y = 3
```

What I want:

```
 x = 3
```

Right now, as I have it, this doesn't set **x** to 3, but **y** to 3. How can I change this so **y** acts as a pointer to **x**. I want to edit **x**, not **y**. Previously, I believe I saw a page about using mutable variables. I don't think I completely understand how variables work in Python.

Comment: Objects of certain types in python are immutable (e.g., int, float, tuple). Objects of other types are mutable (e.g., list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `list`:

```
x = [2]
y = x
y[0] = 3
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because **int type is immutable in python**, and the reference from y variable to x is not created when you try to do that. You can easily check it just by printing id(x) and id(y).

If you don't want to use a list, as Erik McKelvey recommended to you, you can try this https://pypi.org/project/mutableint/

Comment: This does work as I would want it to, but I'd also like it to work with more than just an int. Thanks though :)